# Dynamically create a deep interface from tupple

Tags: typescript

```
const deepProperty = ['example', 'hello', 'world'];

type MakeDeep<A extends string, B> = B;

type A = MakeDeep<typeof deepProperty, string>;

type B = {
  example: {
    hello: {
      world: string;
    },
  },
};
```

I am looking for a way to pass in a deep string and a type and make a interface from it.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? TypeScript doesn't exist at runtime, how do you imagine this will be used?

Comment: It's definitely not possible with `string` paths, it might be possible with tuples using compiler unfriendly recursion which is not recommended. I suggest you try to find another way to express your problem

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Is it possible with a `tuple`?

Comment: @ThomasReggi I think so .. but it's the realm of dark compiler magic, the kind the great wizards do not want us mere  mortals to use and they warn of grave consequences (perf sucks and no guarantee it will work in the future)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir ok nevermind lol

Comment: It's possible i'll post solution

Comment: @ShanonJackson I didn't say it was impossible but it requires tricking the compiler into recursive type aliases, and not the sanctioned kind.. it can be done for sure with tuples ..

Comment: yeah sorry wasn't trying to undercut what you were saying Titian is 100% correct in saying that compiler unfriendly recursion is not recommended, so i would say take the bottom solution with a grain of pure salt

Answer (score 1):

Note i would there are limitations on what the compiler can do in terms of "deep", but this  works hope it helps you

```
const deepProperty: ["example", "hello", "world", "last"] = ['example', 'hello', 'world', "last"];


type MakeDeep<T extends any[]> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends any
        ? Record<T[K], ((..._: T) => any) extends ((_: any, ..._1: infer TAIL) => any) ? MakeDeep<TAIL>[0] extends never ? string :  MakeDeep<TAIL>[0] : string>
        : never;
};


type Test = MakeDeep<typeof deepProperty>[0]


type TestInterface = Record<"example", Record<"hello", Record<"world", Record<"last", string>>>>


const TestAssignment: Test = {
    example: {
        hello: {
            world: {
                last: "STRING"
            }
        }
    }
} //passes

const TestAssignment2: Test = {
    example: {
        hello: {
            world: {
                last: 5
            }
        }
    }
} // fails
```

Comment: ? i don't understand Test is of type TestInterface what are you getting at?

Comment: added two examples that are more robust.

Comment: I would have used `const path = <T extends string[]>(...p: T)=> p;
const deepProperty = path("example", "hello", "world", "last");` for  the path, but other than that looks like you had some fun with it :)

Comment: Hahaha yeah that probably would have been better, yeah definitely had some fun with it recursion literally gives me the same hit of dopamine all my tests lighting up green gives me XD

Answer (score 0):

I'm, really not that great with recursive types, but here's my stab at it. I started with these two types to iteratively convert an array to an object wrapper.

```
type MakeDeep<T, A> =
    T extends Array<string> ? ((...x: T) => void) extends ((h, ...t: infer I) => void) ? { [key in T[0]]: Unwrap<I, A> } : {} : never;
type Unwrap<T, A> = T extends { length: 0 } ? A : MakeDeep<T, A>;
```

The following types are all equivalent:

```
const deepProperty: ['example', 'hello', 'world'] = ['example', 'hello', 'world' ];
type A = MakeDeep<typeof deepProperty, string>;

type B = {
  example: {
    hello: {
      world: string;
    },
  },
};
```